# DataTable does not correctly convert ä,å,ö characters

Tags: .net, powershell, encoding, datatable

I am using [this Out-Table function](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/4208a159-a52e-4b99-83d4-8048468d29dd) to get contents of a `.csv` file as a `DataTable`. But when the file contains `ä`,`å`,`ö` (Swedish characters), the `DataTable` turns them into a `?`. Where in the function should I change the encoding so that the characters look correct in the output? Here is the function code:

```
function Out-DataTable 
{ 
    [CmdletBinding()] 
    param([Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)] [PSObject[]]$InputObject) 

    Begin 
    { 
        $dt = new-object Data.datatable

        $First = $true  
    } 
    Process 
    { 
        foreach ($object in $InputObject) 
        { 
            $DR = $DT.NewRow()   
            foreach($property in $object.PsObject.get_properties()) 
            {   
                if ($first) 
                {   
                    $Col =  new-object Data.DataColumn   

                    $Col.ColumnName = $property.Name.ToString()   
                    if ($property.value) 
                    { 
                        if ($property.value -isnot [System.DBNull]) { 
                            $Col.DataType = [System.Type]::GetType("$(Get-Type $property.TypeNameOfValue)") 
                         } 
                    } 
                    $DT.Columns.Add($Col) 
                }   
                if ($property.Gettype().IsArray) { 
                    $DR.Item($property.Name) =$property.value | ConvertTo-XML -AS String -NoTypeInformation -Depth 1 
                }   
               else { 
                    $DR.Item($property.Name) = $property.value 
                } 
            }   
            $DT.Rows.Add($DR)   
            $First = $false 
        } 
    }  

    End 
    { 
        Write-Output @(,($dt)) 
    } 

} #Out-DataTable
```

Comment: You might not have to do anything with the function. Issue might be with how you get the data. Are you using `Import-CSV`? It has an `-encoding` switch you can use assuming you have at least POwerShell 3.0 I think

Comment: Yes, I saw that I should add the `-Encoding` switch to my import and set it to `default`. Now it is working fine. But please post this as the answer and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

## Your function is fine!

You might not have to do anything with the function. The issue is the data you are passing to the function and therefore how you get the data in the first place.

## Encoding

Are you using `Import-CSV` for example or perhaps `Get-Content`? In either case , as long as you have PowerShell 3.0 or higher, both cmdlets support the `-Encoding` switch. This was the data is imported properly. I'm sure in your case you are using `Import-CSV` but `Get-Content` is worth mentioning.

```
Import-Csv C:\Temp\file.csv -encoding UTF8 
Get-Content C:\Temp\file.csv -encoding UTF8
```